# stop/disable vertical scrolling at a certain point but be able to scroll up the page but not down it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've made a game website that has horizontal and vertical scrolling but I want the website to stop or disable scrolling down the page at the "second arrows"  but be able to scroll up the page.

basically I've already tried "overflow-y:hidden" but i still want to beable to scroll back up the page

https://codepen.io/54x1/full/qBBdXGP

check out my codepen to see my design

code for where i want it:

```
var BotOfWin1 = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight();
var BotOfObj1 = $('.main-rules').position().top + $('.main-rules').outerHeight();
if (BotOfWin1 > BotOfObj1) 
   {
   $('.game-section').css({"display": "block"});
   } else {
      $('.game-section').css({"display": "none"});
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your motivation for disabling scrolling below the second arrows (can the user navigate there other than scolling?). So I'll just go with the assumtion, that you simply want to prevent the user from ever getting there.

Just use `display: none` in CSS to not display the content.

Comment: did that but i actually wanna stop the vertical scrolling below the second arrow so the user can only scroll left to right and up then scroll down once the user has fully scrolled right if u know what i mean

Comment: ps its game website

Comment: scrollleft isnt working on my website it just says zero even when im scrolling https://tawedgame.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

1. Do not display the second page element on pageload

```
.content-second {
  display: none;
}
```

2. On scrolling, check if the page has been scrolled to the very right. If so: display second page element.

```
var win = $(window);
var contentWidth = $('.content-first').width();

win.on('scroll', function () {      
  var scrolledRight = win.scrollLeft() + win.width() >= contentWidth;

  if (scrolledRight) {
    $('.content-second').addClass('show');
  }
});
```

See this [pen](https://codepen.io/derdaani/pen/gOOpXrr) for a simplified example.

Comment: thats basically what im upto on the main frame website https://54x1.github.io/TaweDgame/
except i haven't used "scrollleft()" coz most element appears as 0

Comment: the thing is im trying to make it so they can scroll but not see the big empty spaces, for example, there are four boxes perpendicular to one another the first box has info and the last or fourth box has info

Comment: You have to check `scrollLeft()` on the element that is actually scrolled. In your example, this is the window itself.

Comment: i could make it fade in on scroll but there is still the problem of the big empty space on the left side once everything is faded in

Comment: I'm sorry I can't really figure out what you are trying to achieve / what the problem is. 

Maybe you should take a step back and just make some scribbles of what you want to achieve in a less specific way. By reducing the complexity of your problem you increase the probability of people being able to help you here :)

Comment: sorry man basically im just trying to make the user scroll in a way so they dont see the big empty spaces of nothingness